# Записать ответ асинхронных функций в массив

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте у меня есть такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dsg =  new contract('1', '/json/dsgABI.json');
    console.log(dsg.abi);
});
var contract = function (contractAddress, abiJson){
    var data = [];
    contract.prototype.abi = function(){
        return $.getJSON(abiJson, function(abi){
            return abi;
        });
    }
}
```

Таких вот асинхронных функций будет много и каждая функция возвращает мне какой-то результат. Я хочу записать данный результат в массив чтоб потом доставать данные из массива и что-то с ними делать. К примеру
Внутри контракта вызывать массив после того как все результаты асинхр. функций будут завершены так:

```
    var contract = function (contractAddress, abiJson){
    var data = [];
    contract.prototype.abi = function(){
        return $.getJSON(abiJson, function(abi){
            return abi;
        });
    }
   console.log(data.abi);
}
```

или внешне

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dsg =  new contract('1', '/json/dsgABI.json');
    console.log(dsg.abi);
});
```

Comment: не надо добавлять функцию в прототип _внутри_ конструктора. Это приведет к ошибкам.

Comment: Понял, забрал. Но всеравно не пойму как мне дождаться выполнения всех функций и потом пользоваться массивом data как внутри так и внешне

Comment: @VitaliMalinovski Попробуйте через написать их в виде промиса, а потом воспользоваться `Promise.all`